# Second digit from the right from a huge number

Tags: c++, modular, digit

Now I actually read about modular arithmetic and managed to get the last digit of some number. Okay. But now... How do I get second last digit? Second one on the right. I actually been working on it on several hours straight trying to find a simple solution, this is the best I could come up so far but it's still not it. Could somebody help me please?

This is what I have so far

```
long long powmod(long long n, long long exp)
{
    long long r, result = 1;

    while(exp)
    {
        r = exp % 2;
        exp /= 2;
        if(r == 1) result = result * n % 10;
        n = (n * n) % 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know how to get the right hand digit, then given a number like 1234, what would you divide by to get 123, which you already know how to get the right hand digit of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only asked for the second last digit, how about getting the last two digits, then dividing by ten?

Ie, solve for a^n mod 100, then look at the tens digit.

Comment: Thank you! The easiest solution isn't always that obvious :P

Answer (score 3):

Divide it by ten, round down, and then get the last digit of what remains. :-)

Comment: by "it", do you mean the result of `n^exp`, using ordinary non-modular exponentiation? That works as long as the result fits within a `long long`, but what if the OP wants the second digit of `2^1000`?

Comment: Yes, this is where the problem is at, I know I could just divide it by ten but it wouln't really work for big numbers